# Pagination and searching doesnot work if content are dynamically add in <tbody>part of DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, datatables

I am using  DataTables where onload it shows a list of records example 10 record , After i add next record ie eleventh record(ajax) ,i brings all record  after addition without refresh and append it to `<tbody>` part of  DataTables,  Now my datatable is showing 11 records. but on first page of pagination . In this condition  10 record should be present on first page of pagination and 11th on second page of pagination .But it is not working

```
function save_data(){

$(document).ready(function(){


     var form_data = $("#myform").serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url('reclist/save');?>',
        type:'post',
        datatype:'json',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(info){
             var json = JSON.parse(info);
             if(json.status){
                 var i;
                 for(i=0;i < json.err_input.length;i++){

                     $('input[name="'+json.err_input[i]+'"]').addClass('error');
                     $('input[name="'+json.err_input[i]+'"]').next().addClass('error_msg');
                      $('input[name="'+json.err_input[i]+'"]').next().text(json.err_msg[i]);
                    }
             }
             else{
                **var op = '';
                $.each(json.record,function(k,v){
                op+= "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+v.fname+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+v.lname+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+v.email+"</td>"+
                "</tr>";
                op+= v.fname;**
            });

            $("#rec_list_div").html(op);
            $("#result").html(json.response);
            $("#result").html(json.response);

             }
        },
        errror:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }
     });

      });
//});
}

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
<tbody id="rec_list_div">
      <?php foreach($result as $k):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $k->fname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $k->lname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $k->email;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;       ?>
</tbody>
</table>
    </table>
```

Comment: If i understand it correctly, you clear the table and repopulate it after you run your ajax call, right? In that case, isn't it your back end (/reclist/save) that returns the wrong number of records, and not your js? You have marked the question with PHP but I see no PHP-code anywhere...

Comment: i am getting the correct records in back end it aso appears in  datatables but without pagination ,yes i replace the tbody  part after ajax call success,with new records ,datatables plugin comes with their own pagination script.https://datatables.net/

Comment: plugin doesn't know you are adding rows of html yourself. You either need to use the plugin api to add/remove data or reset the plugin doing what you re doing